# Add boolean checkboxes ng-model to object AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to do something like tree-checkboxes.
I would like to add boolean to children of checked name : ex. after click checkbox at `name` : `eva` - all her childrens will be also checked.
Like that :

```
$scope.messages = 
    {

    "family": [

        {    
            "name": "eva",
            "checked" : true,
            "childrens": [    
                {    
                    "name": "John",
                    "checked" : true,
                    "childrens": [    
                        {    
                            "name": "Jacob",
                            "checked" : true,
                        }
```

My code :

```
<div ng-repeat="key in messages">
  <ul ng-repeat=" (x, y) in key" style="list-style:none;">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="y.check" ng-change="changeValue(shapes, y.name)" /> {{y.name}} {{y.check}}</li>
      <li style="margin-left:15px;" ng-repeat="(a,b) in y.childrens">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="b.check" ng-change="changeValue(shapes, b.name)" /> {{b.name}} {{b.check}}
        <ul style="margin-left:15px;" ng-repeat="p in b.childrens">
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="p.check" ng-change="changeValue(shapes, p.name)" /> {{p.name}} {{p.check}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/lFYUvcTt1W709vam5Dfv?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked your [pinkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/INJejDi7JVyNfMHJ3yyN?p=preview)

As you can see, I update the childrens in the `ng-change` and this function is recursive so all childrens will be checked aswell

```
$scope.changeValue = function(foo, person) {
    for(var i in person.childrens){
      person.childrens[i].check = person.check;
      $scope.changeValue(foo, person.childrens[i]);
    }
};
```

If a person is checked, the children will be checked. If a child is check, it won't update the parent.

Comment: hey, and what if my code looks like that? : http://next.plnkr.co/edit/b18vW7ZxI9EPhFju